# What is the benefit of @MappedSuperclass in Hibernate for inheritance mapping?

Tags: java, hibernate

According to the [Hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance-mapped-superclass), `MappedSuperclass` allows mapping inheritance, where the super class is not treated as an entity, and where polymorphic queries that fetch objects by the base class are not supported.

On the other hand, the [table per class](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance-table-per-class) strategy is similar in terms of the generated schema in the DB, except that it maps the super class to a table if it is not an abstract. However it supports polymorphic queries.

My question is: why would anyone use the `@MappedSuperclass` strategy? Is there a performance issue implied if the parent class is treated as an entity? Any ideas around this is appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

1. *@MappedSuperclass*

- By default, properties of the superclass are ignored and not persistent!
  You have to annotate the superclass with `@MappedSuperclass` to enable embedding of its properties in the concrete subclass tables.
- You can override column mappings from the superclass in a subclass with the `@AttributeOverride` annotation or several with `@AttributeOverrides`.
- You could declare the identifier property in the superclass, with a shared column name and generator strategy for all subclasses, so you wouldn’t have to repeat it. *But it’s optional!*
- The main problem with implicit inheritance mapping is that it doesn’t support polymorphic associations very well. In the database, you usually represent associations as foreign key relationships. If the subclasses are all mapped to different tables, a polymorphic association to their superclass can’t be represented as a simple foreign key relationship.
- Polymorphic queries that return instances of all classes that match the interface of the queried class are also problematic. Hibernate must execute a query against the superclass as several SQL `SELECT`s, one for each concrete subclass.
- A further conceptual problem with this mapping strategy is that several different columns, of different tables, share exactly the same semantics. This makes schema evolution more complex. For example, renaming or changing the type of a superclass property results in changes to multiple columns in multiple tables. Many of the standard refactoring operations offered by your IDE would require manual adjustments, because the automatic procedures usually don’t account for things like `@AttributeOverrides`. It also makes it much more difficult to implement database integrity constraints that apply to all subclasses.

So, this approach is a good chose for the top level of your class hierarchy,
where polymorphism isn’t usually required, and when modification of the superclass
in the future is unlikely.

2. *@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)*

- *The database identifier and its mapping have to be present in the superclass, to share it in all subclasses and their tables. This is no longer optional, as it was for the `@MappedSuperclass` mapping strategy.*
- Note that the JPA standard specifies that `TABLE_PER_CLASS` is optional, so not all JPA implementations may support it. The implementation is also vendor dependent — in Hibernate, it’s equivalent to a `<union-subclass>` mapping in the old native Hibernate XML metadata.
- The advantages of this mapping strategy are clearer if we examine polymorphic queries. The tables are combined with a UNION operator, and a literal is inserted into the intermediate result; Hibernate reads this to instantiate the correct class given the data from a particular row. A union requires that the queries that are combined project over the same columns; hence, you have to pad and fill nonexistent columns with NULL. You may ask whether this query will really perform better than two separate statements. Here you can let the database optimizer find the best execution plan to combine rows from several tables, instead of merging two result sets in memory as Hibernate’s polymorphic loader engine would do.
- Another much more important advantage is the ability to handle polymorphic associations. Hibernate can use a `UNION` query to simulate a single table as the target of the association mapping.

So, this approach is a good chose when you need to use polymorphic queries and associations.

P.S. This is almost verbatim quotation from the excellent book: *Java Persistence with Hibernate* (Bauer, King, Gregory)

Answer (score -1):

meaning a class whose mapping information is applied to the entities that inherit it.